# API or SDK that will allow a computer to detect input from Android?

Tags: android, input, wifi, sensors

I have been searching for a while now for some sort of package allowing me to create a program that remotely detects android inputs on a computer (Linux or Windows preferably) via wifi or bt. I don't need to control my computer, I just need something as simple as pressing a button on my android and having my computer recognize the button is pressed. Anything like this out there or am I hoping for too much?

Essentially; any way to turn my Android into a remote sensor? If not, any recommendations on staring such a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of ways to do this, but your question is a little too vague to answer well because we don't know what you want to do.  Over wifi you could set up an ssh server on the PC and have the phone login over wifi.  Then when the user hits the button send a command to the ssh server.  Or just connect over any predefined socket and send customized commands.

If you want to reduce it to local devices, you can use bluetooth and send data over SPP (serial port protocol) and have a receiver on the PC run the command sent.  Sending data is pretty easy, you just need an app on the PC to do something with it.

Comment: I haven't done much developing on android, it was going to be the start of an expanding learning project for me. Initially I just wanted to have my computer recognize basic input from the android, like having a screen pop up that says your android just pressed 'A'. Eventually I wanted to progress it to me saying "Log Off" and my computer logging off, and other similar actions like that ("Find file 'blah blah blah'", "Open Skype", etc.) Basically help me do simple functions via voice using my phone from anywhere in the building.

Comment: Ok, so I think SSH server and wifi are the way to go, unless you want it only to happen if you're in the same room.  What you need is to respond to events in Android like button clicks and decide what PC command needs to be run, and send that over ssh.